# javascript: Replacing button with a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have this html/javscript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
<p></p>
<?php $linkas= $_GET["linkas"]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getmovies.php?linkas=<?php echo $linkas; ?>',
            success: function(data) {
                document.write(data);
    document.close();
            }
        });
});
});
</script>
```

How can i replace the button with text?
i've tried to replace the button.click with a a.click function but it still does not work.

Comment: you have to specify a href on the `<a></a>` tag

Comment: jQuery has many useful functions such as `text()`, `html()`, `append()`, `prepend()`, and so on. And there's `replaceWith()` function too.
`text()` and `html()` functions deal with `innerText` and `innerHTML`, respectively, while `append()` and `prepend()` attaches or pretaches an element to it. `replaceWith()` function, as you can guess, replaces the original element with new one.

Comment: What do you mean by `replace`. Do you want to display hyperlink instead of button?

Comment: Yes, i would like to click on a link not on a button to run the script. @MUT

Comment: Then replace your button html with `<a></a>'. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/8529/)

Comment: Thanks,  @MUT , This is the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `<button/>` with `<a></a>` and bind click event to element. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/8529/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understood what you are asking. But as far as I understood you want to switch the `button` element with an `a` element.

This can be done like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var href = "http://example.com"
        var content = $(this).text();
        $("button").replaceWith("<a href=\"" + href + "\">" + content + "</a>");
    });
    //... Your Code ...
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var href = "http://example.com"
     var content = $(this).text();
     $("button").replaceWith("<a href=\"" + href + "\">" + content + "</a>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="my-link">Click Me</a>
<p></p>
<?php $linkas= $_GET["linkas"]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-link").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getmovies.php?linkas=<?php echo $linkas; ?>',
            success: function(data) {
                document.write(data);
    document.close();
            }
        });
});
});
</script>
```